# How to select a list of data in MySQL and insert with one Query with SQL Language

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Select Statement that fetches more than 1 data

```
set @name := select name from users;
```

Now I want to insert all of them with one Query

for example

```
insert into users2 (name , created) Values (@name , NOW())
```

it returns this error

```
Error Code: 1242
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

is there any way to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax must be like this

```
insert into users2 (name , created)
select name, NOW()  from users
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
insert into users2 (name , created) 
 select name, NOW() from users;
```